# Vue: TypeScript Error when using Vue.mixin

Tags: typescript, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building SSR application using Vue.js.

I faced typescript error when I tried to [this](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html#client-data-fetching).

```
Vue.mixin({
    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
        const { asyncData } = this.$options
        if (asyncData) {
            asyncData({
                store: this.$store,
                route: to
            }).then(next).catch(next)
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
})
```

And this is the error.

```
Property '$options' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue> | ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>'.


Property '$store' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue> | ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>'.
```

How can I avoid this error? 
I'm the newbie in typescript.
Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution (which is not good, but works)
=> 

    (this as any).$store

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
Vue.mixin({
    beforeRouteUpdate ((this as Vue), to, from, next) {
        const vm = this as Vue;
        const { asyncData } = vm.$options
        if (asyncData) {
            asyncData({
                store: vm.$store,
                route: to
            }).then(next).catch(next)
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
})
```